# Render recursive binary tree json in angular view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, recursion

I have a recursive json structure as below, in which i would like to dynamically render the html view template in angular.

The key is as follows: as long as it has the properties **objects**, it may have the property **objects** or **object**, where objects is always an array and object is always an object. it may loop infinitely depending on the json.

I have defined the view as follow but it has limitation to the depth as i defined in the view as opposed to the view should render according to json.

Index.html

```
<div ng-repeat="subtopic in json.subtopic">
    <div ng-if="subtopic.objects">
        <div ng-repeat="subtopic in subtopic.objects">
            <div ng-if="subtopic.objects">
            </div>
            </div ng-if="object">
            </div>
        </div>

        </div ng-if="object">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div ng-if="object">
    </div>
</div>
```

JSON.json

```
{
    subtopic: [
        {
            "title": "title 1",
            "subtitle": "title 2",
            "objects": [{
                "title": "123"
                "label": "456"
                "objects": [
                    {
                        "object": {
                            "object-1": "123",
                            "object-2": "456"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "object": {
                            "object-1": "123",
                            "object-2": "456"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }]
        },
        {
            "title": "title 1",
            "subtitle": "title 2",
            "objects": [{
                "title": "123"
                "label": "456"
                "objects": [
                    {
                        "object": {
                            "object-1": "123",
                            "object-2": "456"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "object": {
                            "object-1": "123",
                            "object-2": "456"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }]
        },
    ]
}
```

Comment: Would recommend having a look at using ng-include for recursion. This guy has a good article on it http://benfoster.io/blog/angularjs-recursive-templates

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I have resolved it with the link you give

Comment: @vincentsty If you have resolved the issue, I would suggest better to post it as answer and you can also mark your answer as accepted. will be useful to the community members.